# How to use abbrev in MacVim

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

I'm new to mvim and I'm not sure how to use commands that have been saved in my vimrc file like the following:

```
"Load the current buffer in Chrome - Mac specific.
abbrev chrome :! open -a Google\ Chrome %:p<cr>
```

(note: This was originally:

```
"Load the current buffer in Chrome - Mac specific.
abbrev ff :! open -a FireFox.app %:p<cr>
```

)

I'm just confused as how this abbrev works all together and couldn't find an answer on google :\  Maybe someone here could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines create an abbreviation for a commonly used command. In this case, it is creating an abbreviation for opening the current buffer in a particular application. For instance if you were working on a file called `index.html` and you entered the command `:chrome` in vim, it would open index.html in Chrome.

For the three major Mac browsers, use the following lines in your `.vimrc` file:

```
" Open the current buffer in a web browser
abbrev ff :!open -a Firefox.app %:p
abbrev chrome :!open -a Google\ Chrome.app %:p
abbrev sf :!open -a Safari.app %:p
```

This works because the `:!` at the beginning of each abbreviation definition tells vim to execute a shell command. In these cases, the shell command is `open -a [WHICHEVER_BROSWER].app` using the current buffer `%:p`.

Here is some further reading:

- [Vim Wiki article on Abbreviations](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_abbreviations)
- [Blog Post about Opening Buffers in External Apps](http://www.emoosx.me/2011/11/vim-opening-current-buffer-in-external.html)

Comment: Thank you, so abbrev is used when I am running a command (usually by typing ':') - this helps so much!

Comment: Is it possible to open a MacVim line as a url in a browser? Instead of the buffer as a document.

Answer (score 0):

While using `abbrev` works in this scenario it's normally used for saving typing or fixing common spelling mistake:

```
iabbrev mmm myultRalonganDrandomlycapiTAlizedemailadDress@example.com
iabbrev teh the
```

If you want to execute a command, I think normal mappings are conceptually better suited. Here is what I have in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
let os=substitute(system('uname'), "\n", "", "")
if os == "Darwin" || os == "Mac"
    nnoremap <F12>f :exe ':silent !open -a firefox %'<CR>
    nnoremap <F12>c :exe ':silent !open -a "google chrome" %'<CR>
    nnoremap <F12>o :exe ':silent !open -a opera %'<CR>
    nnoremap <F12>s :exe ':silent !open -a safari %'<CR> 
elseif os == "Linux"
    nnoremap <F12>f :exe ':silent !firefox %'<CR>
    nnoremap <F12>c :exe ':silent !chromium-browser %'<CR>
    nnoremap <F12>o :exe ':silent !opera %'<CR>
endif
```

Comment: Certainly another way it could be done - I only focused on the `abbrev` method because the asked was confused and asked specifically about it. I do like your method - especially the `os ==` part.

Comment: Oops, I forgot the most important part where `os` is defined.

Comment: so, if I understand this right abbrev = command (pressing ':') and iabbrev is an inline abbreviation used for spelling or shortcut text.  I also do really like your mapping the keys thing too, certainly very elegant (specially the os part)

Comment: although my question was a bit unclear I believe that Paul has it right - I was more interested in finding out how abbrev works in vim.  Though props to you for helping solve the other issue behind my abbrev one ;)

Comment: `abbrev` and `iabbrev` are the same thing. One is for command-line mode and the other is for insert mode but both are used to help type less. I don't like to use it for accessing often used commands.